# Reusing the result of SBT compilation between Travis or Github Actions jobs

Tags: scala, caching, sbt, travis-ci, github-actions

Does anyone know if it is possible to have a multi-stage Travis build that uses SBT (latest 1.4.3 version) and for each stage to reuse the compiled code from the previous one?

I tried with caching, but it does not seem to work (I hope I am just missing something).
What I have is a first “Compile” stage, and then a second “Tests” stage where two jobs are run in parallel (unit tests and integration tests).

What I want is that the Compile compiles everything (including test code) and then both the next stage just picks up where the compilation left.

I managed to organise the build to do that but:

- either the compilation is re-done in each step or
- by caching the whole `./` the compilation is saved…but then it ignores every new change I push (obviously).

The caching config I am using comes from the sbt docs:

```
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.cache/coursier
    - $HOME/.ivy2/cache
    - $HOME/.sbt
```

Any idea?

*(alternatively, if you know this is a problem of Travis and **it can be made to work properly in Github Actions, that would be ok too**)*

Comment: Caching is not meant for storing build artifacts between stages. You would need to use a shared storage, such as S3. See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/share-files-s3/

Comment: Also, if you want coverage, you *have to* recompile your code in order to let the coverage tool add instrumentation, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: interesting. Can I ask why it is not meant for storing `.class` files between stages? For bigger artefacts I can understand, but what would the rationale be for compiled code?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new Travis feature (in beta) that allows you to share files from one job with subsequent jobs in a build: [workspaces](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/using-workspaces/)

```yaml
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: warm_cache
      script:
        - echo "foo" > foo.txt
      workspaces:
        create:
          name: ws1
          paths:
            - foo.txt
    - stage: use_cache
      workspaces:
        use: ws1
      script:
        - cat foo.txt || true
```

Also, SBT 1.4 allows you to push build artefacts to a Maven server and fetch then again later: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Remote-Caching.html